# What are the differences between librt and libeio for asynchronous I/O, and why would I choose one over the other?

Tags: c, asynchronous, io, librt

I *really* want to put more in the body to explain the question… but the title really covers it all. As far as I can suss, `librt` is more “official” (it’s a standard part of `libc`?), but I also remember seeing that Node.js uses `libeio`. Which should I spend more time looking into? What about portability? How different are their APIs?

(I’d appreciate it if somebody with ≥1,500 rep could add the tags “libeio” and “librt” to this question, as I cannot.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libeio wraps standard calls in threads, and handles a large swath of the common system calls.

librt only has a few calls -- read and write, but not, for example, stat.

Comment: Hm. In many cases, though, it seems (from the documentation) that `librt` may be hardware-supported, instead of simply put together with judicious application of `pthread`s. Wouldn’t that imply `librt` has much more potential to be performant?

Comment: In theory, yes. But it's probably hard to do much better than a good thread-based implementation.